# Could not resolve project, none of the consumable configurations have attributes

Tags: java, gradle, build, project

My Jenkins pipeline showed error message like this:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':distTar'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :ProjectA.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :ProjectA:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :ProjectB.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :ProjectB:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :ProjectC.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :ProjectC:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :ProjectD.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :ProjectD:
         - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :ProjectE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :ProjectE:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :ProjectF.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :ProjectF:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I followed some tutorials online, but it seems that none has published the complete steps of how to configure the dependencies with configurations attributes.

My build.gradle goes something like this:

```
    plugins {   
    id "java-library"   
    id "application" 
    }

    apply plugin: 'java' 
    apply plugin: 'java-library' 
    apply plugin: 'eclipse' 
    apply plugin: 'application'

        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
                    maven {
                    url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                }   
                            flatDir {           dirs 'lib'      }                           }

configurations {    
    implementation

// A configuration meant for consumers that need the API of this component
    exposedApi {
// This configuration is an "outgoing" configuration, it's not meant to be resolved
     canBeResolved = true
// As an outgoing configuration, explain that consumers may want to consume it
                canBeConsumed = true
            }
// A configuration meant for consumers that need the implementation of this component
            exposedRuntime {
                canBeResolved = true
                canBeConsumed = true
            }

// declare a configuration that is going to resolve the compile classpath of the application
  compileClasspath.extendsFrom(implementation)

// declare a configuration that is going to resolve the runtime classpath of the application
            runtimeClasspath.extendsFrom(implementation)

        }

        configurations.compile.resolutionStrategy {
            force project }

        dependencies {  
    implementation project(':ProjectA')     
    implementation project(':ProjectB')     
    implementation project(':ProjectC')     
    implementation project(':ProjectD')     
    implementation project(':ProjectE')     
    implementation project(':ProjectF')         
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')   
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../ProjectA/lib', include: '*.jar')   implementation fileTree(dir: '../ProjectA/lib/gson', include: '*.jar')      
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib/symbol', include: '*.jar')    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib/symbol/lib', include: '*.jar')    implementation fileTree(dir: '../ ProjectC/C/framework/libraries', include: '*.jar')    
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../ ProjectC/C/framework', include: '*.jar')

            api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

            api 'junit:junit:4.12'

            // Use JUnit test framework
                // This dependency provides the public API for writing tests and extensions     

    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.4.1'         
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.4.1'      
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-migrationsupport', version: '5.4.1'    
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: '5.4.1'      
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: '5.4.1'

    testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-engine', version: '1.4.1'    
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.5.0-M1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

            //This dependency provides TestFX
            testCompile group: "org.testfx", name: "testfx-core", version: "4.0.15-alpha"
            testCompile group: "org.testfx", name: "testfx-junit", version: "4.0.15-alpha"

            testCompile group: 'org.testfx', name: 'openjfx-monocle', version: 'jdk-9+181.1'

            implementation group: 'org.testfx', name: 'testfx-junit5', version: '4.0.15-alpha'

            // This dependency runs tests in JUnit 5, 4, 3 
            testRuntime(
                    'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.1',
                    'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.4.1',
                    'org.testfx:openjfx-monocle:jdk-9+181.1'
            )
                                                         }
        test {
            useJUnitPlatform()

            testLogging {       events "passed", "skipped", "failed"    }    }

        wrapper {   gradleVersion = '5.5.1' }

        eclipse {       classpath {
                    downloadSources = true
                    downloadJavadoc = true  } }

        task sourceJar (type : Jar) {   classifier = 'sources'  
            from sourceSets.test.allSource }

        mainClassName = 'id.blablu.test.main.StartMainTest'


        compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

        processResources  {
            from ('src/test/java') {
            include ('**/*.properties')   }     from('C:/workspace/ProjectD/src'){      include ('**/*.properties')       } }

        sourceSets {        
test{       
   java {           
      srcDir 'src/test/java'        
      }     
   }     
}

        def ArrayList vmArgs = ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"] if(JavaVersion.current() >= JavaVersion.VERSION_11) {   vmArgs = vmArgs
        + [
                            "--add-modules", "javafx.base",
                            "--add-modules", "javafx.graphics", 
                            "--add-modules", "javafx.controls",
                            "--add-modules", "javafx.fxml",
                            "--add-modules", "javafx.media",
                            "--add-modules", "javafx.swing",
                            "--add-modules", "javafx.web"
                        ] }

        run {
            doFirst {
                if(JavaVersion.current() >= JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9) {
                    jvmArgs = vmArgs + [
                        "--module-path", classpath.asPath
                    ]
                } else {
                    jvmArgs = vmArgs
                }
            } }

        application {
            if(JavaVersion.current() >= JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9) {
                applicationDefaultJvmArgs = vmArgs + [
                        "--module-path", "../lib"
                    ]   } else {        applicationDefaultJvmArgs = vmArgs  } }
```

If anyone has complete configurations of dependencies and its attributes, please show me or

tell me please how to configure the configurations attributes.

Thanks.